# Simple probability probem

Tags: probability

Consider a family with 4 children. What would be the probability that the family has 2 boys and 2 girls if there is equal probability of the family having a girl or a boy?

My approach:
Since there is equal probability, the probability of having a girl is $\frac 14$.The same applies to the probability of having a boy. Hence won't the required probability be $\frac {1}{4^4}$

Comment: The probablity of having a girl in any given birth should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possible orders for the children, each specific order has equal probability ($\frac{1}{16}$ in this case). Hence the probability is $\frac{6}{16}=37.5\%$